# Difficulty using same PHP class when POSTing data from javascript and PHP contexts

Tags: php, javascript, http

I have a PHP class called FormController whose constructor currently validates some $_POST variables and throws an exception if they're not all set. The FormController should eventually return the address of the next page.

So my PHP page would something like:

```
session_start();
try {
    // controller needs certain variables set in the $_POST
    // superglobal to work properly.
    $controller = new FormController();
    echo $controller->nextPage();
} catch(Exception e) {
    // Handle exception here
}
```

my javascript code (jQuery):

```
$.post('next_page.php', {
    form_variant: form_variant,
    person: person,
    last_page: last_page,
    direction: "forward"
},
function(data) {
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    window.location = response.new_page;
});
```

Initialing the POST request from javascript this is fine, but I am also working with some legacy code and would need to get the new page address from the form controller but I can't figure out how to call the FormController because that needs to use the $_POST variable.

One compromise is that I could have the form controller accept normal arguments and validate any post requests before I construct the FormController. This way I can contruct it from a PHP page.

Sorry for the length of this question, but can anyone tell me how I could make a POST request from within a PHP page? Or even if there is a better way I could be designing this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your formController allow $_POST vars being sent to be overwritten with a passed array:

```
public function __constructor($data = array())
{
    if(!sizeof($data))
    {
        $data = $_POST;
    }
}
```

Then send it directly when required:

```
$controller = new FormController($data);
```

Comment: Hey. That's a really great idea. Thanks for that. I really wanted to keep the validation within the FormController class so that I can test it all in one place. It just seemed neater to me. Cheers.

Comment: You could also switch it to be if(sizeof($data)){ $_POST = $data; }

Answer (score 0):

You are using ajax just to get the post url and then do a redirection?

Why not just post to the nextpage, and let the nextpage decide what your want to forward to.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I do have to do it this way. I didn't make it explicit, but on my app people fill out a selection of forms which can be presented in any combination. I f more than one person applies, then the forms have to be presented once for each person etc. So i'm never really sure what the next page actually will be until my Form controller works it out.

Comment: Yes, your Form controller should decide what to do next, not do a redirection. For the most simple way, you can just include your the next page which decided by your Form controller, through it's not good.